# Flashing an image with specific frequency

Tags: c#, image, winforms, visual-studio, animation

I am trying to show an image in a specific frequency (make it flashing).

I already add the image in a picture box but I don't know how to make it flash, any ideas?

Comment: nope I don't want to use gifs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a timer and set your picturebox visibility to the opposite on each tick? Non tested code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
   {

    Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent),
    Interval = 5000,
    Enabled = true
   }
}

 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
    //your timer is executing
     myImageBox.Visible = !myImageBox.Visible
 }
```

Comment: added example with frequency

Comment: I mean if I need it to flash with frequency 500hz for example

Comment: 500hz would be interval = 2 (thats milliseconds)

Comment: Well as Timers have only a resolution of 15-25 ms and the eye only of 16 Hz, 500Hz will certainly not work perfectly. But It will look perfectly awful I'm sure.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too:

```
public static void Main()
{ 
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;  //Declared in your 'Form.Designer.cs'
    timer.Interval = 1000; //Equals the 1 second
    timer.Start(); //Always use 'Timer.Stop', when you need stoping the Timer
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox.Visible = !pictureBox.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note, this answer wont' work on windows app, its is for Web. If you are using C# with ASP.Net Then JQUERY's toggleClass() 
will work for you. Don't go server side.

```
setInterval(
    function(){
         $('#imgId').toggleClass('on');
    },500
   );
```

Comment: using the wording "picture box" and only tagging it c# i believe this is related to windows forms and not web-based content

Comment: @zedd, I knew and I agree too , but since OP's reputation was giving me a newbie  kind of feel and generally newbiew misses some tags..